# Protected question statement visible in test review of question

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits, protected-questions

In a review of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/658433/mysterious-misdirected-chinese-traffic-how-can-i-find-out-what-dns-server-an-h), the 'Protected by Community' template is visible in the test. Unfortunately, I flubbed the screenshot of the actual test question, so here's what it looks like afterward.
[image]

Comment: @Sven I'm not clear on how the test review question mechanism works (selected by mods? script? random? something else?).

Comment: Mod's don't  have anything to do with that. AFAIK it's some script that selects question based on certain criteria, e.g. many upvotes for a question would get it selected for an off-topic review. This script has *many* issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next build will clear the protected display info for audits.  Thanks for the report.

Comment: I just had [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/660217/getting-503-error-from-varnish-but-varnishlog-doesnt-tell-much) with an active open bounty as **test question** in my review queue of Close Votes, where similarly that banner was visible too.